# Javascript/ajax not sending empty fields to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am a beginner in programming and i have a java script function that sends the variables of a form to a php script.

In the form i have two tables that hold two dropdowns each.
I can click the plus button to clone the first table row and i can click delete to remove the clones.

The max amount that can be generated is limited to 3 for nativelang and to 6 for practlang.

I have set all the variables that can be generated in the php and the javascript already and if i generate the max amount then it all works fine.

But if i don't generate any or just a few then the ajax.send is not doing anything, actually the form button stops working.

I suspect it is because of the expected data from the already declared variables that are empty because i didn't generate the drop downs.

This is the code that might cause the problem:

```
ajax.send("u="+u+"&e="+e+"&p="+p1+"&c="+c+"&g="+g+"&ct="+ct+"&nl="+nl+"&nll="+nll+"&nl0="+nl0+"&nll0="+nll0+"&nl1="+nl1+"&nll1="+nll1+"&nl2="+nl2+"&nll2="+nll2+"&pl="+pl+"&pll="+pll+"&pl0="+pl0+"&pll0="+pll0+"&pl1="+pl1+"&pll1="+pll1+"&pl2="+pl2+"&pll2="+pll2+"&pl3="+pl3+"&pll3="+pll3+"&pl4="+pl4+"&pll4="+pll4);
```

and this error is returned:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of nullsignup.php:954 signupsignup.php:893 onclick

How can i make it send the field even if its empty? or is it the php code?
I assumed the php would just save the fields that hold data and if a variable has no data then it is just saved as empty into the database right?

So thats why i thought it must be the javascript.

Would be super great if someone could help me to make this work :)

Sign up script:

```
function signup(){
var u = _("username").value;
var e = _("email").value;
var p1 = _("pass1").value;
var p2 = _("pass2").value;
var c = _("country").value;
var g = _("gender").value;
var ct = _("city").value;
var nl = _("nativelang").value;
var nll = _("nlanglevel").value;
var nl0 = _("nativelang0").value;
var nll0 = _("nlanglevel0").value;
var nl1 = _("nativelang1").value;
var nll1 = _("nlanglevel1").value;
var nl2 = _("nativelang2").value;
var nll2 = _("nlanglevel2").value;
var pl = _("practlang").value;
var pll = _("planglevel").value;
var pl0 = _("practlang0").value;
var pll0 = _("planglevel0").value;
var pl1 = _("practlang1").value;
var pll1 = _("planglevel1").value;
var pl2 = _("practlang2").value;
var pll2 = _("planglevel2").value;
var pl3 = _("practlang3").value;
var pll3 = _("planglevel3").value;
var pl4 = _("practlang4").value;
var pll4 = _("planglevel4").value;
var status = _("status");

if(u == "" || e == "" || p1 == "" || p2 == "" || c == "" || g == "" || ct == "" || nl == "" || pl == ""){
    status.innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form fields marked with a star";
} else if(p1 != p2){
    status.innerHTML = "Your passwords do not match";

} else {
    _("signupbtn").style.display = "none";
    status.innerHTML = 'Email has been sent!';
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
       if(ajax.responseText.trim()!= "signup_success"){
        status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        _("signupbtn").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                window.scrollTo(0,0);
                _("signupform").innerHTML = "<div id=\"status\">OK "+u+", <h2>check your email</h2> inbox and junk mail box at <u>"+e+"</u> in a moment to complete the sign up process by activating your account. You will not be able to do anything on the site until you successfully <h2>activate your account!</h2></div>";
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send("u="+u+"&e="+e+"&p="+p1+"&c="+c+"&g="+g+"&ct="+ct+"&nl="+nl+"&nll="+nll+"&nl0="+nl0+"&nll0="+nll0+"&nl1="+nl1+"&nll1="+nll1+"&nl2="+nl2+"&nll2="+nll2+"&pl="+pl+"&pll="+pll+"&pl0="+pl0+"&pll0="+pll0+"&pl1="+pl1+"&pll1="+pll1+"&pl2="+pl2+"&pll2="+pll2+"&pl3="+pl3+"&pll3="+pll3+"&pl4="+pl4+"&pll4="+pll4);
}
```

}

Script for the buttons that add or delete rows in the table(table holds dropdowns):

```
    var ncount = -1;
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#addBtnNative').on('click', function(e){
        if($('.nativelangdrop').length < 4) {
            ncount++;
            var initialn_row = $('tr.initialn').first().clone();
            var nativelang_name = initialn_row.find('td:eq(0) select').attr('name'); // first td select
            var nlanglevel_name = initialn_row.find('td:eq(1) select').attr('name'); // second td select
            initialn_row.find('td:eq(0) select').attr('name', nativelang_name + ncount);
            initialn_row.find('td:eq(1) select').attr('name', nlanglevel_name + ncount);
            var nativelang_id = initialn_row.find('td:eq(0) select').attr('id'); // first td select
            var nlanglevel_id = initialn_row.find('td:eq(1) select').attr('id'); // second td select
            initialn_row.find('td:eq(0) select').attr('id', nativelang_id + ncount);
            initialn_row.find('td:eq(1) select').attr('id', nlanglevel_id + ncount);
            $('table.nativelanguages').append(initialn_row);
        }
    });

});

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#remBtnNative').on('click', function(e){
        if($('.nativelangdrop').length > 1) {
            ncount--;
            var initialn_row = $('tr.initialn').last().remove();

        }
    });

});
var pcount = -1;
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#addBtnPract').on('click', function(e){
        if($('.practlangdrop').length < 6) {
            pcount++;
            var initialp_row = $('tr.initialp').first().clone();
            var practlang_name = initialp_row.find('td:eq(0) select').attr('name'); // first td select
            var planglevel_name = initialp_row.find('td:eq(1) select').attr('name'); // second td select
            initialp_row.find('td:eq(0) select').attr('name', practlang_name + pcount);
            initialp_row.find('td:eq(1) select').attr('name', planglevel_name + pcount);
            var practlang_id = initialp_row.find('td:eq(0) select').attr('id'); // first td select
            var planglevel_id = initialp_row.find('td:eq(1) select').attr('id'); // second td select
            initialp_row.find('td:eq(0) select').attr('id', practlang_id + pcount);
            initialp_row.find('td:eq(1) select').attr('id', planglevel_id + pcount);
            $('table.practlanguages').append(initialp_row);
        }
    });

});


$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#remBtnPract').on('click', function(e){
        if($('.practlangdrop').length > 1) {
            pcount--;
            var initialp_row = $('tr.initialp').last().remove();

        }
    });

});
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST["u"])){
include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");

$u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['u']);
$e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
$p = $_POST['p'];
$g = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['g']);
$c = preg_replace('#[^a-z ]#i', '', $_POST['c']);
$ct = $_POST['ct'];
$nl = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['nl']);
$nll = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['nll']);
$nl0 = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['nl0']);
$nll0 = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['nll0']);
$nl1 = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['nl1']);
$nll1 = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['nll1']);
$nl2 = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['nl2']);
$nll2 = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['nll2']);
$pl = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['pl']);
$pll = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['pll']);
$pl0 = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['pl0']);
$pll0 = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['pll0']);
$pl1 = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['pl1']);
$pll1 = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['pll1']);
$pl2 = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['pl2']);
$pll2 = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['pll2']);
$pl3 = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['pl3']);
$pll3 = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['pll3']);
$pl4 = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['pl4']);
$pll4 = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['pll4']);
$ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));

$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$u' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
$u_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
// -------------------------------------------
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$e' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
$e_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($u == "" || $e == "" || $p == "" || $g == "" || $c == "" || $ct == "" || $nl == "" || $pl == ""){
    echo "The form submission is missing values.";
    exit();
} else if ($u_check > 0){ 
    echo "The username you entered is alreay taken";
    exit();
} else if ($e_check > 0){ 
    echo "That email address is already in use in the system";
    exit();
} else if (strlen($u) < 3 || strlen($u) > 25) {
    echo "Username must be between 3 and 25 characters";
    exit(); 
} else if (is_numeric($u[0])) {
    echo 'Username cannot begin with a number';
    exit();
} else {

    $p_hash = md5($p);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, gender, country, city, nativelang, nlanglevel, nativelang0, nlanglevel0, nativelang1, nlanglevel1, nativelang2, nlanglevel2, practlang, planglevel, practlang0, planglevel0, practlang1, planglevel1, practlang2, planglevel2, practlang3, planglevel3, practlang4, planglevel4, ip, signup, lastlogin, notescheck)       
            VALUES('$u','$e','$p_hash','$g','$c','$ct','$nl','$nll','$nl0','$nll0','$nl1','$nll1','$nl2','$nll2','$pl','$pll','$pl0','$pll0','$pl1','$pll1','$pl2','$pll2','$pl3','$pll3','$pl4','$pll4','$ip',now(),now(),now())";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    $uid = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO useroptions (id, username, background) VALUES ('$uid','$u','original')";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

    if (!file_exists("user/$u")) {
        mkdir("user/$u", 0755);
    }

    $to = "$e";                          
    $from = "email@site.com";
    $subject = 'blah | Account Activation';
    $message = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title> Message</title></head><body style="margin:0px; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;"><div style="padding:10px; background:#333; font-size:24px; color:#CCC;"><a href="http://www.dandani.eu"></a>Account Activation</div><div style="padding:24px; font-size:17px;">Hello '.$u.',<br /><br />Click the link below to activate your account when ready:<br /><br /><a href="http://www.dandani.eu/activation.php?id='.$uid.'&u='.$u.'&e='.$e.'&p='.$p_hash.'">Click here to activate your account now</a><br /><br />Login after successful activation using your:<br />* E-mail Address: <b>'.$e.'</b></div></body></html>';
    $headers = "From: $from\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo "signup_success";
    exit();
}
exit();
```

}

HTML:

```
<legend class="legend"><h3>Select your languages</h3></legend>

    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>
        <div class="lala">



                <table class="nativelanguages">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Spoken language</td>

                        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">Level</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="initialn">
                        <td>
                            <select class="nativelangdrop" id="nativelang" name="nativelang" required>
                            <option value="none" selected disabled>Select language</option>
                            <?php
                                        if ($file = @fopen('txt/languages.txt', 'r')) {
                                            while(($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
                                                echo "<option>{$line}</option>";
                                            }
                                            fclose($file);
                                        }
                                        ?>
                        </select></td>

                        <td>
                        <select class="langleveldrop" id="nlanglevel" name="nlanglevel" required>
                            <option value="none" selected disabled>Select level</option>
                                <?php
                                        if ($file = @fopen('txt/levels.txt', 'r')) {
                                            while(($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
                                                echo "<option>{$line}</option>";
                                            }
                                            fclose($file);
                                        }
                                        ?>
                        </select>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </table>

                <div class="pmbutton">
                <button href="javascript:;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="addBtnNative">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
                <button href="javascript:;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="remBtnNative">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="lala">


                <table style="float:left; margin-top:20px;" id="plang" class="practlanguages">
                    <tr>


                        <td>Practicing language</td>

                        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">Level</td>


                    </tr>

                    <tr class="initialp">
                        <td>
                            <select class="practlangdrop" id="practlang" name="practlang" required>
                                <option value="none" selected disabled>Select language</option>
                                    <?php
                                        if ($file = @fopen('txt/languages.txt', 'r')) {
                                            while(($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
                                                echo "<option>{$line}</option>";
                                            }
                                            fclose($file);
                                        }
                                        ?>
                        </select>
                        </td>

                        <td><select class="langleveldrop" id="planglevel" name="planglevel" required>
                            <option value="none" selected disabled>Select level</option>
                                <?php
                                        if ($file = @fopen('txt/levels.txt', 'r')) {
                                            while(($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
                                                echo "<option>{$line}</option>";
                                            }
                                            fclose($file);
                                        }
                                        ?>
                        </select>
                        </td>




                    </tr>
                </table>


                <div class="pmbutton">
                <button href="javascript:;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="addBtnPract">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
                <button href="javascript:;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="remBtnPract">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
                </div>


            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to S.E. in order to clearly identify the problem, we need to see the specific code that is causing the issue. Keep this in mind when asking future questions.

Comment: okay i put it into the post already but now i added the suspected line in an extra codebox. thanks

Comment: What is `_("username").value` exactly? are you using `undersore.js` or something?

Comment: its from function _(x){
 return document.getElementById(x);
}

Comment: What does it return if the element is not found in the document?

Comment: it does nothing, the button just stoppes working and nothing is sent at all.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of nullsignup.php:954 signupsignup.php:893 onclick this is the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you get your element values, try changing them to like this:

`var u = _("username").value ? _("username").value : '';`

This uses a [Ternary Operator](https://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/javascript/ternary.php) to set the value of `u`.

The syntax is: `condition ? result-if-True : result-if-False;`

**Basically, this says, if `_("username").value` returns a value, assign that value to `u`, if not, set the value of `u` to `""` (an empty string)**

Below is a contrived example using regular jQuery method `$("#username").val()` I imagine it will also work with `_("username").value` though Im not sure what the benefit of doing `_("username").value` is having never seen this before myself.

---

```js
var u = $("#username").val() ? $("#username").val() : 'not found';
alert(u);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks alot that worked. i changed the vars in question to this: var nl0 = $("#nativelang0").val() ? $("#nativelang0").val() : 'None'; and it works now, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use chrome developer tools so you can see what jquery.ajax send

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#improving-network-performance

in php, you can see what are incoming using

```
print_r($_POST)
```

and

```
print_r($_GET)
```

Comment: oh this helped to find that ajax is unable to send empty values: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of nullsignup.php:954 signupsignup.php:893 onclick  thanks for this!